# What to do with planet nine if it is a Black Hole?

Tags: physics, hard-science, space-travel, black-holes, astrophysics

[Recently it's been theorized that "planet nine" may be a black hole.](https://www.space.com/planet-nine-black-hole-test-lsst.html)

If this was the case what could we do with it? What unresolved problems in physics could be solved by having such a thing possibly within our reach?

Additionally, if experiments were performed on a black hole like this, what would they look like? Do we shine lasers at it? Drop entangled atoms into it?

I'm also interested in the kind of spacecraft required to get the experiment to the black hole. Getting into a close orbit around this thing would require a huge amount of fuel. Perhaps a series of flyby missions like New Horizons are more feasible?

Comment: Possibly a better question for Physics SE?

Comment: I'm actually trying to cross post there but I need to wait 40 minutes.

Comment: I think this is off-topic for Worldbuilding - it's an interesting question, but it's more of a what-if than a question about worldbuilding, unless alessandro is building a world.

Comment: @HDE initially the thought was how do I turn this news story into a Greg Egan esqe near future science fiction story.

Answer (score 7):

> If this was the case what could we do with it?

We could use it as a powerplant to establish an Oort-cloud civilization. Dropping garbage mass onto it in a controlled manner would produce far more energy per unit fuel than even fusion power would, and literally any mass is suitable as fuel.

> What unresolved problems in physics could be solved by having such a
> thing possibly within our reach?

We won't know for sure until we actually do some experiments and find out if they reveal anything new. However, it might help us uncover more information to narrow down the search for a theory of quantum gravity, by permitting us to perform experiments on strong gravitational fields over very short distances.

> Additionally, if experiments were performed on a black hole like this, what would they look like? Do we shine lasers at it? Drop entangled atoms into it?

We shine lasers at it, we point particle detectors at it (testing Hawking radiation--we'd only expect extremely dim radio waves from something that size, but if we can reliably detect them, that would be *amazing*, and if we detect anything else, well, that could easily launch some theorist's careers), and we fire beams of various types of particles near it to see exactly how it deflect's their paths.

> I'm also interested in the kind of spacecraft required to get the experiment to the black hole. Getting into a close orbit around this thing would require a huge amount of fuel. Perhaps a series of flyby missions like New Horizons are more feasible?

A flyby is really not practical. The black hole would be far too small and to difficult to see to target accurately. A flyby wouldn't realistically be able to do anything more interesting than narrowing down the exact location of the black hole based on observation of the spacecraft's path deflection, so that later missions can target it more accurately.

Getting into a close orbit right away wouldn't really be necessary. Now, getting into any kind of orbit when you can't aerobrake generally does require large amounts of fuel, so the first *serious* mission to study the thing would have to be fairly beefy. The trick would be to aim as close as is considered safe to where we think the black hole is, and then perform a burn at periapsis (perhaps "peritrypa" for the closest approach to a black hole?) to take advantage of the Oberth effect and establish a high elliptical orbit. The spacecraft would need an extremely good celestial navigation system (and tidal sensors might actually be useful in this case as well) to be able to identify when its path starts being significantly bent by close approach to the black hole. So, several telescopes for tracking the positions of known solar system objects with high parallax. Setting up a system of artificial tracking beacons as a series of precursor missions, or using a fleet of spacecraft to act as reference beacons, might be a good idea.

After that first satellite insertion, though, said satellite can provide much more detailed information about the precise location of the black hole, which means future missions can take advantage of the black hole to brake without needing ridiculously huge amounts of fuel; instead, they could fire pellets ahead of themselves on paths which will curve around the black hole and slam back into an impactor plate on the spacecraft and slow it down.

Comment: Are you referring to the Penrose process? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penrose_process#:~:text=The%20Penrose%20process%20(also%20called,from%20a%20rotating%20black%20hole.

Comment: @DWKraus No. The efficacy of the Penrose process depends on the spin parameter of the black hole. That is certainly something we could test, but you can turn arbitrary mass into energy with high efficiency just by lower it on a rope attached to a generator, or dumping a ton at once and capturing the radiant thermal energy, regardless of the spin parameter.

Comment: I'm not questioning it's true, but you might want to explain that to those of us who are only intuitive about physics. It doesn't SOUND efficient. It would make a nice addition to the answer. Great answer BTW.

Comment: @DWKraus Dropping a mass in a gravitational field releases gravitational potential energy. Dropping it all the way to the event horizon of a black hole can release up to 42% of the mass's equivalent energy, an efficiency beaten only by antimatter annihilation.

Comment: @ Logan R. Kearsley  Cool. How do you manage to collect that energy? I'd think it would be spraying all over in an exponentially expanding bubble, or sucked back in. It sounds like quite a trick. Is there a stream of particles, or can you somehow collect it at the event horizon? This could be an answer all on it's own.

Comment: @DWKraus the thing is only the size of a grapefruit so it's pretty easy to enclose. The energy coming off the black hole as matter is dropped in will probably be x-rays or gammarays. I think you can just have a set of thermal powerplants with a flat x-ray absorbing surface on the black hole side and big radiators on the other (to provide the temperature differential) in close orbit around the black hole. I'm not sure how close you can get before tidal forces start becoming an issue, it depends on how you design the generators I suppose. Other concerns are how hot you can get the xray absorbers

Comment: @DWKraus Like I said, you can just lower it on a rope. Use the unreeling of the rope to spin a shaft that turns a generator. Or if you want to be messy about it, you drop a bunch of stuff at once which will form into an accretion disk, and just capture the thermal radiation coming off of it. You need a spinning black hole to make that maximally efficient, though (otherwise the accretion disk gets cut off to early by a maximal ISCO radius, and most of the radiation is in fact "sucked in").

Comment: @Logan R. Kearsley Thanks, that makes it clearer.

Comment: @LoganR.Kearsley with the rope thing, isnt that only possible if you aren't in orbit of the black hole? Like you've built a stationary ring around it? I don't think that's structurally possible without some far future materials. At 100km gravity is 10k times stronger than on earth so this ring needs to be huge.

Comment: @alessandro Nope. Consider a space elevator: it's in orbit, but you can still reel in the tether in and out, and you can extract energy from letting things slide down the tether.

Comment: @LoganR.Kearsley you're basically suggesting a skyhook but I don't think you can't extract any energy below the center of mass of the hook.

Comment: @alessandro You would be incorrect about that.

Comment: @LoganR.Kearsley I think you're right. Anything you drop from the bottom of your skyhook would fall in an elliptical orbit with its apoapsis at the bottom of the hook, but by hooking a generator to one end of the rope it should slow down and spiral in. Hopefully this gives you enough energy to efficiently reboost your skyhook.